# toArray give error in cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to get all product related to 'products' table. But when $product_key blank
,the code will give errors. I want the blank array without elements. My code in the controller like that.

```
$ProductTable        = TableRegistry::get('products');    
$ProductData = $ProductTable->find('All') ->where(['product_key' => $product_key]) ->first() ->toArray();
```

---

Comment: When $product_key is missing you will get an error. If you want to allow null values you should use where(['product_key IS' => $product_key])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the {$ProductData} inside if condition like this:

```
$ProductTable        = TableRegistry::get('products');    
$ProductData = $ProductTable->find('All') ->where(['product_key' => $product_key]) ->first();


if($ProductData){
          $ProductData = $ProductData->toArray();
      }else{
          $ProductData = [];
      }
```

Comment: $ProductData will be retrieved from ,$ProductData->toArray();
How could I get check it before getting the value..??

Comment: Dear ,
data is retreived when you call ->first() method.
toArray() is just used to convert an entity object to Array.

Comment: ->first() returns an entity(IF RECORD EXIST) or null (your case) which cannot implement toArray(). Just remove the ->first() and check if the result is not empty then retrieve the 1st index of the array. Another way explained by @tphobe9312

Comment: For your benefit, You can access your model in the controller by $this->ModelName->find(); and $this->find(); in Model but   "TableRegistry::get('categories');" this is mostly usefull when you want to access other model inside the model.

Comment: Thanks, tphobe9312.. for your help.